# C++ "string subscript out of range" problem

Tags: c++, string, subscribe

Please help with debugging. The compiler gives me an error 'string subscript out of range error'.

The idea of the part of the program is to read in several lines from a text file and combine them into a single string. The last line has a semicolon ';' at the end.

For example:

"The cat

sat on the mat

by itself";

The final string is: "The cat sat on the mat by itself";

There are my codes:

```
int main()
{
    string temp;
    char temps[1000];
    while (true) {
        cout << "Please input file name: ";// user input file name
        getline(cin, fileName);
        ifstream inFile(fileName);
        if (!inFile.is_open())// error
        {
            cout << "File cannot be opened" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        
        while (true) {
            inFile.getline(temps, 500);//read line from file
            temp = temps;

            while (temp[temp.length()-1] != ';') {// This while loop should combine each line which has no ';' at the end. However, when I load the example4.txt
                inFile.getline(temps, 500);      // the system will warn that "string subscript out of range". I do not know how to fix.
                temp = temp.append(temps);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Here is where the error occured:

```
while (temp[temp.length()-1] != ';') {// This while loop should combine each line which has no ';' at the end. However, when I load the example4.txt
                inFile.getline(temps, 500);      // the system will warn that "string subscript out of range". I do not know how to fix.
                temp = temp.append(temps);
            }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp.length()` will become zero for empty line and then `temp[temp.length()-1]` will be out-of-range. You should check for that.

```
//     add this condition
//     |
//     v
while (temp.length() == 0 || temp[temp.length()-1] != ';') {
    inFile.getline(temps, 500);
    temp = temp.append(temps);
}
```